# business ranking based on transaction data

Tags: ranking

I have some customer (say 10,000 customers) transaction data of many stores, what would be a good approach to rank these stores?

The transaction data is of entire year, and the transaction data including transaction amount, type of store, location of store ... etc.

And how would one evaluate such ranking algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far in terms of approach say classification or clustering? How about providing some sample data or maybe a reproducible example?

Comment: How do you determine a "better" store in this context? What metric will you use?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it could be framed as a [learning to rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) problem.

Business primarily care making money, so start with profit and revenue.